# Logical word problem with derivatives

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, derivatives

seeking some math advice on this problem. I think I got the answers but I would love some feedback if I am wrong. :)

> You have a job where you are selling gadgets. Suppose `p` is the price in dollars of a gadget and `q = f(p)` is the quantity sold in hundreds. The revenue in thousands of dollars is `R = p * f(p)`, dependent on the price. Interpret the problems into statements.

1. $f(15) = 3$
2. `$f (^-1) (60) = 3$
3. $\frac{(R(20) - (R(15)}{5} = 12$

---

1. For # 1, I solved by thinking about the number of gadgets relative to cost. This means *when the price increases from 15 to 16, the company expects to sell about 300 more gadgets.*
2. For # 2, I solved by thinking *when the company sells 300 gadgets, the price is $60 dollars each.*
3. For #3, R represents the revenue so I think that *if the price increases from 15 to 20, then the company will increase by 12,000 dollars.*

Comment: We're missing information. Are you supposed to interpret points 1, 2, 3 in words?

Comment: @TobyMak Yes, I am supposed to interpret the problems into statements.

Answer (score 1):

I think there are slight errors in all three. Here are some notes.

For #1, your interpretation is a way to interpret the statement $f'(15)=3$, but not $f(15)=3$. Remember, $q=f(p)$, so all it's saying is if $p = 15$, then $q = 3$. If the price is set to $\$15$, then the quantity sold is $300$. It's not a rate of change.

On #2, I'm assuming you meant the notation to read $f^{-1}(60) = 3$. If that's the case, then think about what $f^{-1}$ represents. You're still assuming that $p$ is the input of $f^{-1}$ and $q$ is its output, but if $q = f(p)$, then we must have $p = f^{-1}(q)$. So, $p$ and $q$ switch places between input/output when we go from $f$ to $f^{-1}$.

Then, note that you have $q = 60$ and $p = 3$. So, it's saying that when the price is set to $\$3$, the quantity sold will be $6000$ units. It's the inverse of the relationship in #1.

For #3, again, I'm making an assumption about your notation, I'm assuming it's meant to read $\frac{R(20)-R(15)}{5}=12$. Again, your answer is close, but there are two mistakes.

First, it should be $\$1200$, not $\$12{,}000$ (quantity is measured in 100s, and $12\cdot 100 = 1200$).

Second, your answer is for $R(20)-R(15) = 12$, not for $\frac{R(20)-R(15)}{5} = 12$. If the price goes from $\$15$ to $\$20$, then the revenue will increase by an amount $R(20)-R(15)$.

So what's the division by $5$ supposed to represent? Notice, $20-15 = 5$, so $\frac{R(20)-R(15)}{5} = \frac{R(20)-R(15)}{20-15} = \frac{\Delta R}{\Delta p}$.

This is the *average* rate of change in revenue per dollar increase in price from $\$15$ to $\$20$, not the *total* increase in revenue (which is how you interpreted it). So, a more accurate reading would be that as the price increases from $\$15$ to $\$20$, the revenue increases by an average of $\$1200$ per $\$1$ increase in price.